# Failed to display API response with label

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, amazon-web-services, serialization

I am new to ASP.NET . Recently, I have created my own api.As a result , I have decided to create a web form to test the api . However, the response is not showing, I believe that I have done everything correctly.

**My code behind for the web form**

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using FoodBlog.Model;


namespace FoodBlog
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var weatherData = new WeatherData();
            var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://1ibewdli19.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Working/blogid/1");
            string replacedString = json.Replace("<", "");
            string replacedString1 = replacedString.Replace(">", "");
            WeatherData wdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(replacedString1);

            Label1.Text = wdata.description;
        }
    }
}
```

**Model :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FoodBlog.Model


{

    public class WeatherData
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string iconDesc { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**JSON Data is working fine(Using Postman)**

```
    {
    "id": "<Humid and mostly cloudy throughout the day.>",
    "icon": "<partly-cloudy-day>",
    "time": "<1532448000>"
}
```

Comment: Use postman, or inspect the response/request via the developer tools of your browser (Usually F12).

Comment: JSON and model do not match

Comment: @Nkosi Aha , thanks for the hint !

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string can't match your `model`, you can try to use [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute to mapper your JSON string and model properties.

```
public class WeatherData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string iconDesc { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

or use this class you will get the JSON data.

```
public class WeatherData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```